# Javascript search for dropdown inside knockout data-bind foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Using knockout js

I have setup my dropdown inside a table as:

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
<tr>
  <td id="tdName"><select class="form-control" data-bind="options: $parent.ddl, optionsText: 'firstName', value: selectedValue, optionsCaption: '--Select--',  attr: { name: 'Items[' + $index() + '].Name', id: 'Items[' + $index() + '].Name'}"> </select></td>
 </tr>
```

So it creates multiple rows of dropdowns. The above in html looks as below:

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="options: $parent.ddl, optionsText: 'firstName', value: selectedValue, optionsCaption: '--Select--',  attr: { name: 'Items[' + $index() + '].Name', id: 'Items[' + $index() + '].Name'}" name="Items[0].Name" id="Items[0].Name"><option value="">--Select--</option><option value="">Alex</option><option value="">Sam</option> </select>
```

I have a save button where I want to validate if this dropdown was selected on or not.

So I am trying to use the below code on save button click:

```
     var selectList = $('#tdName > select');         
        for (var ddl of selectList ) {               
            if (ddl.value == '') {
                ddl.className = "required text-danger form-control ddl-error";                }
        }
```

In my console when I debug I can see the selectList as: select#Items[0].Name.form-control

So basically what I am trying to do above is loop through all the ddl and if no selection is made add the error class to it so that it is highlighted.

The issue is ddl.value is always '' so the dropdown is always highlighted.

Not sure here if I am looping though correctly here

I have my jsfiddle here as:

https://jsfiddle.net/aman1981/7wqvr854/51/

To see in action click add row, get data to populate the dropdown.

Would appreciate inputs.

Comment: Change to `var selectList = $('#tdName > select > option').get();`

Comment: @haim770 this gives me the entire array of items. The table can multiple rows so there can be multiple select. Thats why I added ID & Name column to the select so that I can distinguish between them. Again what I want is to check if user made any selection in the dropdown.  I have created a new jsfiddle with you changes as : https://jsfiddle.net/sq8m054L/1/

Comment: You need to specify the 'optionsValue' in your data-bind attribute, so that Knockout knows which property to bind to the 'value' field of your select options.  See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Comment: Cant have optionsValue. Value and optionsValue dont go well together. I remember using it before and had some issues.

Comment: `optionsValue` and `value` do work together, I have amended your js fiddle to demonstrate but as mentioned below there are better ways to do this, by iterating over your items and ensuring the selectedValue() is not blank...     https://jsfiddle.net/7wqvr854/55/

Comment: Well that does validates but it gives JS error Text is undefined. See your fiddle also it throws error when optionsValue is added

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't access the DOM to check for selected values. You're already binding them to your viewmodel!

The validity check inside the `Save` method can access `items` directly:

```
self.save = function() {
  var rows = self.items();

  if (!rows.length)
    alert("You cannot save an empty table");
  else if (!rows.every(r => r.selectedSeperator()) 
    alert("Some rows do not have a selected seperator");
  // etc.

};
```

Comment: This works for the selectedseparator but not for my first dropdown. The first time if an empty row is added and save is clicked items have length as one so it does not validate. Secondly if you add one row and select all values in that dropdowns. Then add another row, items count is again 2 so it does not validate here also. I wanted to access DOM so that I can highlight exact dropdown where no selection was made

Comment: You can find the dropdowns that do not match the requirements by using `filter`. You can then set some `invalid` flag on those rows by `forEach`ing over the invalid rows.